# Circular reference in Kotlin data class could generate stack overflow error

Tags: kotlin

I have a question regarding data classes in Kotlin.
Say we have two classes with a circular reference:

```
data class Foo(
    var bar: Bar? = null
)
```

```
data class Bar (
    var foo: Foo? = null
)
```

and the main function:

```
fun main() {
    val f = Foo()
    val b = Bar()
    f.bar = b
    b.foo = f
    f.hashCode()
    b.hashCode()
    //println(f)
    //println(b)
}
```

the code that Kotlin auto generates will make the main function go in stack overflow. You can try this in [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Q60TEhRUj).
Is this an expected behaviour? Note that this is a basic example, but this will happen in real life situation where, for example, instead of a reference of Foo in Bar we can have a List, a Set or a generic collection of Foo.
Shouldn't Kotlin generate some sort of compiler error or this happens even in other languages?
[same thing but in Java](https://repl.it/@jacopozagoli/KotlinJavaTest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be considered a bug. [Here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-does-kotlin-implement-equals-and-hashcode/940) is a correspondence with a Kotlin developer, discussing something that may be another bug, but the important bit is:

> By default, no specific equals and hashCode are generated (thus, they
> check object identity).
>
> **For** **data** **classes**, hashCode and equals are based on property values.
> I’ll write algorithm steps in words instead of pseudocode:
>
> hashCode:
>
> 1. **Calculate hashCode for each property** declared as constructor parameter in current class
> 2. Return h1 × 31n−1 + h2 × 31n−2 + … + hn

This is then the expected behavior, and obviously breaks on your example with step 1. In your "real" world example using the `Array.hashCode` might be the solution, but it seems like in this contrived one (though I have seen constructs such as these, that's why forward declarations exist in C/++...). I would file it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues. They may just tell you to set the hashCode to the default one for regular classes using object ID.

[poipoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12904585/poipoi) found this was in fact reported years ago, which I missed at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16244

so data classes with circular references must provide their own `toString` and `hashCode`. Too bad this is not documented behavior.

Comment: I came up with this question because I had a situation with classes similar to Foo and Bar, and I had to add an instance of Foo to a MutableSet (MutableSet part of Kotlin standard lib) which will calculate the hashCode. I'll report the bug later and post updates

Comment: @poipoi Good idea. For now you can work around this by implementing `hashCode` yourself.

Comment: @poipoi and even if it is a `wontfix`, I would ask them at least to document the default behavior.

Comment: I was going to file an issue but I found it was already reported 4 years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16244

Comment: @poipoi Good find. Looks like they will not fix this, and you need to implement your own `toString` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will smash the stack; and no, I'm not aware of any language compilers which protect against this.

In the general case, I don't think problematic circular references *could* be spotted by a compiler, without also picking up perfectly valid circular references.  (For example, any doubly-linked list structure contains circular references; but because none of the usual things you'd want to do would follow them in a circle, it's extremely unlikely to be a problem.)

It's only a problem here because these are data classes, which in some sense ‘contains’ their members, at least as far as some of the autogenerated methods go.

In the Java standard library, some of the collection classes explicitly give undefined behaviour if a collection contains itself, either directly or indirectly.  For example, the [Collection.addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) function:

> The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this collection, and this collection is nonempty.)

While an implementation *could* check for that and thrown an exception, doing so in a way which works for arbitrary levels of nesting would probably have a very significant impact on performance, so it's not required by all implementations — and I don't know any that do.

Even for the specific case of data classes in Kotlin, there's no obvious way — especially if you allow the two classes to be compiled at different times.  You could disallow data class members which were themselves data classes — but that wouldn't stop members being non-data classes which themselves contained data classes (and had hand-written methods delegating to them).  (And it would prevent a lot of non-circular references too.)

Comment: Any implementation whose hash does not depend on it's members will not break on this. Since Kotlin chose to implement a default hash code, they should either specify in their docs that circular references break the default implementation, or change it (in my opinion of course). They could just as easily chose to do the same thing as they do for regular classes.